# Update company based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have user table with fields

```
Name, email, CompanyId (foreign key to company table), TenantId
```

And table companies that have fields

```
Name, TenantId
```

For now `TenantId` in companies = 0

I need to find a user for every company, get TenantId from the user table, and change TenantId for every company in the company table to TenantId from user

I wrote this SQL script for it

```
   UPDATE companies
SET TenantId = (SELECT  a.TenantId
FROM (SELECT* FROM companies) AS c
LEFT JOIN abpusers AS a ON (c.Id = a.CompanyId) AND (c.Id = a.CompanyId)
ORDER BY c.Id, a.Id)
WHERE TenantId = 0;
```

But I get this error because it returns a collection.

> [21000][1242] Subquery returns more than 1 row

How do I need to update SQL query?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  At first glance, your data model doesn't make sense.  You say, for instance, that you have a foreign key reference to a `companies`, but `companies` doesn't seem to have a primary key.  And why is `tenantId` stored in two places?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Joins` than `Sub Query`

```
    UPDATE Companies
    LEFT JOIN abpusers a on companies.Id = a.CompanyId
SET Companies.TenantId = a.TenantId
WHERE Companies.TenantId = 3;
```

Comment: Also I have always one user with null in TenantId, so I need to filter it too, so get all user where it's not null

I try to add `LEFT JOIN abpusers A ON C.Id = A.CompanyId AND A.TenantId != null`

But have error `[23000][1048] Column 'TenantId' cannot be null`